# Converting .html file to .csv file but .html file contains logs and it has nested tables

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup, file-conversion

I am trying to convert a .html file which contains logs in tabular form and it has nested tables.
i am converting it to .csv file.
one column has error report and it as new table inside that column. i want to convert that whole table into plain text.
trying to do this in python using beautifulsoup but no luck yet. the data from nested table scatters to all columns of parent table and doesent stick to the original column.
anything i could do?

used python with beautifulsoup library
doesent give the desired output

Comment: please share the file or some snippet that gives a better idea of what you're working with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Converting HTML files with nested tables to CSV while preserving the structure can be a bit challenging. BeautifulSoup is a great library for parsing HTML, but it may require additional manipulation to properly handle nested tables.

To achieve the desired output, you can use BeautifulSoup along with some custom Python code to parse the HTML, extract the data, and organize it correctly into a CSV format. Here's a step-by-step approach to help you achieve that:

Parse the HTML file using BeautifulSoup.

1. Find the parent table and extract its headers.
2. Find all rows in the parent table.
3. For each row, find the nested table (if it exists) in the relevant column.
4. Extract the data from the nested table and append it to the respective cell in the parent table.

Here's a Python code snippet to help you get started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def extract_nested_table_data(table_cell):
    # Helper function to extract the data from a nested table cell
    nested_table = table_cell.find('table')
    if not nested_table:
        return ''

    # Process the nested table and extract its data as plain text
    nested_rows = nested_table.find_all('tr')
    nested_data = []
    for row in nested_rows:
        nested_cells = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
        nested_data.append([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in nested_cells])
    
    # Convert nested_data to a formatted plain text representation
    nested_text = '\n'.join(','.join(row) for row in nested_data)
    return nested_text

def convert_html_to_csv(html_filename, csv_filename):
    with open(html_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')

        parent_table = soup.find('table')
        headers = [header.get_text(strip=True) for header in parent_table.find_all('th')]

        with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow(headers)

            rows = parent_table.find_all('tr')
            for row in rows[1:]:  # Skipping the header row
                cells = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
                row_data = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in cells]

                # Extract data from nested table (if it exists) and append to the row
                for idx, cell in enumerate(cells):
                    nested_data = extract_nested_table_data(cell)
                    row_data[idx] += nested_data

                csv_writer.writerow(row_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html_filename = 'input.html'
    csv_filename = 'output.csv'
    convert_html_to_csv(html_filename, csv_filename)
```

This code assumes that your nested table data is comma-separated. If it's not, you may need to adjust the separator accordingly. Additionally, consider other delimiters if your nested table contains commas.

Remember that handling complex HTML structures may require further adjustments to this code, depending on the specifics of your data. Nonetheless, this should serve as a good starting point to tackle the task.